# What are the gtk 3 python constants for the scroll events

Tags: python, gtk3, mousewheel

I've been searching for the constants for python gtk 3 using PYGObjects.  Specifically what are the enum constants for the scroll events.  'gi.repository.Gdk' object has no attribute 'SCROLL_UP'.  The events are listed [here](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gdk-constants.html#gdk-scroll-direction-constants) and is not working from the [pygi-convert.sh](https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/pygi-convert.sh)
I have included sample code that pinpoints the issue.  Thanks.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def on_destroy (widget):
    Gtk.main_quit()
    return False

def scroll_notify_event(w, e):
    print e.direction
    if e.direction == Gdk.ScrollDirection.UP:
       print "You scrolled up"
    elif e.direction == Gdk.ScrollDirection.DOWN:
       print "You scrolled down"

def event(eventbox, event):
    print("Event: %s" % event)

def create ():
    window = Gtk.Window()
    window.connect("destroy", on_destroy)
    window.add_events( Gdk.EventMask.SCROLL_MASK )

    eventbox = Gtk.EventBox()
    eventbox.connect("event", event)
    window.connect('scroll-event', scroll_notify_event)
    window.add(eventbox)

    window.show_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Doc location for the scroll event found [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/enums.html#Gdk.ScrollDirection.UP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `Gdk.ScrollDirection.UP`.

The docs you linked are pygtk docs. pygtk is not gtk3. The relevant docs can be found [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/).

Comment: Thanks.  That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to find this command to make a button able to scroll
button.add_events( Gdk.EventMask.SCROLL_MASK )

Comment: Welcome to SO... Is this an answer, or a comment posted as an answer because you can't post comments?

Comment: Todd, in regards to Gerry's answer, it may depend on the gtk-widget. I am a ruby user mostly, but the pygobject code works ok; and, for example, gtk-entry does not by default respond to scrolling events. So one has to add that event specifically, which may be useful information for others who read this thread here. What I, in ruby-gtk, did, was to also check for the name event.event_type.name() being == 'GDK_SCROLL' before then checking via the .directio() method on the event scroll. There, the constants work in ruby; I assume for python this is the same due to pygobject being the same really.